# Добавление данных из List<T> в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, ado.net

Есть `List<Change>`

```
    public class Change
    {
        public string TableName { get; set; }
        public ChangeType ChangeType { get; set; }
        public string PrimaryKey { get; set; }
        public string ColumnName { get; set; }
        public string OldValue { get; set; }
        public string NewValue { get; set; }
    }
```

и есть сущность, которая имеет такие же свойства, но и несколько своих.

Я могу без цикла добавить все элементы из списка в сущность или все таки требуется цикл по списку ?

Comment: А в чём проблема с циклом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то тогда так.
Предположим, что у вас есть сущность `ChangeEntity`. Чтобы обойтись без цикла, мы можете воспользоваться функцией [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.entity.dbset.addrange(v=vs.113).aspx), используя предварительно метод [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) для преобразования объекты `Change` в сущность `сhangeEntity`

```
сhangeEntityObjects.AddRange(changes.Select(c => new ChangeEntity()
{
    TableName = c.TableName
    ....
});
```